# Laravel polymorphic relation detach and delete

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

Can anyone tell me how to get this done? When I delete an album I want to delete all uploaded files from the server, delete the relation AND delete the photos from the database. Deleting the files works (but if there is a better way to do this, by all means, enlighten me):

```
foreach($album->photos as $photo)
{
    File::delete($photo->path);
    File::delete($photo->thumbnail_path);
}
```

But my main question is this. I want to detach the relation between the album and the photos, and also delete the photos from the database after the actual files are removed. But I can only either remove the relation using detach, or delete the photos from the database using delete. Whichever one I use first works, because afterwards either the relation is gone or the photos are gone, ofcourse.

How can I do both? Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Edit:

Doing it like this right now, good approach or is there a better way?

```
public function delete(Album $album)
{
    $ids = array();

    foreach($album->photos as $photo)
    {
        File::delete($photo->path);
        File::delete($photo->thumbnail_path);

        $ids[] = $photo->id;
    }

    $album->photos()->detach();

    Photo::whereIn('id',$ids)->delete();

    $album->delete();

    flash()->success('Album deleted');

    return back();
}
```

Comment: Try this  \File::delete($file);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the migration you can just say ON DELETE CASCADE, that basically will remove any connected photos to the deleted album

Comment: Thanks, I did want to do that, but I figured I had to link it to some foreign id. But clearly that is not the case, silly me.